# add a "list" into add meta box : problem

Tags: custom-post-types, list, metabox

i found a code searching through stackexchange --> to create a "list" inside a meta box of a custom type, BUT, i don't see anything appearing in this meta box, except the input field (which comes from the example page from the CODEX : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), is it a problem with WP_QUERY inside a function?

Can you please tell me what is the magic trick to fix this? in my callback function, i added this code :

```
function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {
  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

  // The actual fields for data entry
  echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
  _e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field"/>';


 $s_query = new WP_Query( array(
 'suppress_filters' => false,
 'post_type' => 'movies'));
while($s_query->have_posts()):$s_query->the_post();

    $sname = $post->post_title;
    $s_output2 ='';
    $s_output2 .= '<option value="'.$post->ID.'" >';
    $s_output2 .= $post->post_title;
    $s_output2 .= '</option>';
    echo $s_output2;

endwhile ;
wp_reset_query();
}
```

But as i said, the "list" doesn't appear. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the declaration of the [HTML select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) which options are his children so just add something like this:

```
function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

    // The actual fields for data entry
    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
    _e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field"/>';

    //the actual select tag
    echo '<label for="my_list_field">';
    _e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<select name="my_list_field" id="my_list_field">';
    $s_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'post_type' => 'movies'));
    while($s_query->have_posts()):$s_query->the_post();

        $sname = $post->post_title;
        $s_output2 ='';
        $s_output2 .= '<option value="'.$post->ID.'" >';
        $s_output2 .= $post->post_title;
        $s_output2 .= '</option>';
        echo $s_output2;

    endwhile ;
    echo '</select>';
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: @Bainternet : Alright thanks a lot, it works with SELECT, however the "post" is not recognized, which let me with blank "option" content, it seems that $post->post_title or any of the $post is not recognized. Do you know what i could do for that? edit:i tried with "the_title()" or "the_ID" but it's not working.

Comment: @Paul_p declare `global $post;` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @Bainternet : no, thanks but it doesn't work. "post_title" is in green in Netbeans, which normally means that it doesn't exist, or is not declared. What would you do? post_title and ID are in green...

Comment: They are green because they are a part of the $post Object which is generated every time you use the_post() inside a loop , and i guess that Netbeans doesn't know that :)

Comment: @Bainternet : Ok maybe the time for the navigator to 'refresh', but now it works well! :) thanks a lot for your help! Cheers

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: @Bainterner : hi, sorry i'm a bit confused : after that, i want to save the checked option : problem : add_post_meta($post->ID, "new_key", $meta_value); what do i write for $meta_value? how can we reach the selected "option" ? Thanks a lot again, sorry for this new question ;)

Comment: you use `$post['my_list_field']` which will hold the value of the selected option.

Comment: @Bainternet : ok no need to bother with the "selected" to know which "option" has been selected? thanks a lot again